# How to import [op] function in mod tests?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, deno

I am testing a function with an attribute `#[op]` (deno_ops proc_macro op):

```
#[op]
#[instrument(name = "op_xyz", skip_all, ret)]
async fn xyz() -> Result<U256, deno_core::error::AnyError> {...}
```

I have written the tests like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::op_xyz;

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_op_get_latest_nonce() {
      let res = op_xyz().await;
      ...
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
expected function, found `op_xyz`
```

Below is what the VS Code Rust plugin says about the error:

```
Auto-generated by deno_ops, i.e: #[op]
Use op_get_latest_nonce::decl() to get an op-declaration you can include in a deno_core::Extension
```

**Note:** The function is working perfectly & I can test it outside the `mod tests`, so the issue seems with importing `op_xyz` inside it due to its `#[op]` attribute.

**Usage outside mod tests**

```
    #[op]
    #[instrument(name = "op_xyz", skip_all, ret)]
    async fn xyz() -> Result<U256, deno_core::error::AnyError> {...}

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_op_xyz() {
      let res = op_xyz().await;
      ...
    }
```

Then running `cargo test test_op_xyz -- --nocapture` returns the correct value.

Comment: Can you show a usage example outside `mod tests`? You mentioned that works.

Comment: @PitaJ I've added the example test outside `mod tests` which is working correctly.

Comment: Can you try `use super::*;` instead?

Comment: @PitaJ Still getting the same `error[E0618]: expected function, found op_xyz`

Comment: Can you post your Cargo.toml

Comment: Maybe see what the `op` procedural macro is doing with [`cargo-expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand)?